# Property missing error when I add a new static event on Silverlight

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, events, properties

HI there,

I have added a static event with the following code:

```
public class TypeChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
     public Types TypeSelected { get; set; }
}

public delegate void TypeChangedHandler(TypeChangedEventArgs eventArgs);

public static event TypeChangedHandler TypeChanged;
```

And I do get an event handler for TypeChanged, then I typed some code like MessageBox.Show("Hello World") there and tried to compile, then I get the following error:

The property "TypeChanged" does not exists on the type "Selector" in the XML namespace 'clr-namespace:Test'

I am not sure what's missing, can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your event is static - remove that keyword and it compiles fine.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown how you're trying to reference the `TypeChanged` property. Could you show either the XML you're using or the C# code?

Are you perhaps trying to effectively subscribe to the event via an *instance* of `Selector`?

Comment: <local:Selector x:Name="SelectorControl" 
  Grid.Row="1" 
  Grid.Column="2" 
  Size="300" 
  SizeChanged="SelectorControl_SizeChanged" 
/>